# How to add a user in the role Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I can not quite understand how do users with different rights, here are the rules:

```
{"rules": 
    {"authentication": 
        {"users": 
            {"$uid": {
                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid || root.child('authentication').child('users').child('auth.uid').child('isAdmin').val() == true",
                ".write": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('authentication').child('users').child('auth.uid').child('isAdmin').val() == true",
                ".indexOn": [
                    "email"
                ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

user: [link screen user](http://prntscr.com/d1qg4k)

Realtime Database:

```
{
 "users" : {
 "-KVVe4Ncd5Qnm5r37zVp" : {
   "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
   "isAdmin" : true,
   "name" : "admin"
 },
  "-KVVeADyh07mBXBFImtq" : {
   "email" : "djvang92@gmail.com",
   "isAdmin" : true,
   "name" : "Ivan"
  }
 }
}
```

Firebase script:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAfeEpMopsPWnowiv1uEWYINgk6V_ohvG4",
  authDomain: "spalah-1358.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://spalah-1358.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "spalah-1358.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "300000265085"
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)


export const db = firebase.database();

export const auth = firebase.auth()



console.log(auth);

// var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
// var provider = new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider();




export default {

  // User object will let us check authentication status
  user: {
    authenticated: false,
    data: null,
    message: ''
  },
  login(context, creds, redirect) {
    console.log('Login...');
    let self = this;
    let email = creds.email;
    let password = creds.password;
    let promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    console.log(email, password);

    // Redirect to a specified route
    if(redirect) {
       // context.$router.go(redirect) 
       // console.log(context.$router);       
    }

    promise
    .then(user => {
       self.user.authenticated = true
       self.user.message = false
    })
    .catch(e => {
      self.user.message = e.message
      console.log(e);
    })

  },
  signup(context, creds, redirect) {
    console.log('Sign Up...');
    let email = creds.email
    let password = creds.password
    let promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    promise
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        self.user.message = false
      })
      .catch(e => {
        self.user.message = e.message
        console.log(e);
      })
  },
  logout() {
    let self = this
    auth.signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
      console.log('Log-out successful');
      self.user.authenticated = false
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      console.log('Log-out error');
    });
  },
  provider(context, creds, redirect) {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // Accounts successfully linked.
      var credential = result.credential;
      var user = result.user;
      // ...
      console.log(credential);
      console.log(user.photoURL);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      // ...
      console.log(error);
    });

  },
  checkAuth() {
    let self = this
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('Connect:', user);
        self.user.authenticated = true
        self.user.data = user
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('No connect:');
        self.user.authenticated = false
        self.user.data = null
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I can not understand how to test it in Javascript...
(I make application to vue.js)

Thank you!

Comment: Firebase just launched support for role based access via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party here but may as well answer this for anyone looking.
The current method for assigning roles to users with Firebase is to use custom claims. To do this you mint your own JWTs and add in the custom claims at this point. You can use Firebase Functions to do this or you could do this on your own server.

You can see the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).